# PHP Docblocks using an interface in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, interface

I have a class that is based on an interface. The methods are correctly documented in the interface, however they only show up as hints if you do not document the method in the implementation class *at all*. (that is no docblock).

I'd like to put some form of docblock in, rather than just nothing, as it just seems a bit wrong having a method with nothing above it at all and it looks like the documentation has been forgotten.  I've tried an empty block and @see, neither of which work (both break autocomplete further up the chain).  Ideas?

Comment: I'd regard that as a bug, for which there's probably already something in the NB bugs list (at a guess). Have a search over there? `:)`

Comment: For already documented methods you should use only `{@inheritdoc}` in docblock. It is still [not implemented](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202763), but at least doe not break return types, so method chaining with hints is still available.